# Magento 2.3.4 installation issue "The default website isn't defined. Set the website and try again."

Tags: magento2.3, installation, localhost, default

I clone the repository on local and try to run the installation command, but its just throwing an error that

```
In WebsiteRepository.php line 159:
The default website isn't defined. Set the website and try again.
```

I delete .env, roll back my composer to 1.9.0 nothing worked yet.
I am not sure what causing the issue, try to check the logs but it not showing anything much, I added a screenshot hope that can help something.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything as suggested but the issue still remains, after that I remove/disabled all the third-party modules and tried again and now it worked fine, after installation, I enable/install modules again.

hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have env.php still presented in your project.

Just delete env.php file and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try with `rm -rf  dev/tests/integration/tmp/sandbox*` inside the project directory.
Then if that does not work have a look at the steps below:

- Debug into `\Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository::getDefault`, where the actual exception is thrown.
- The first call of `\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager::get` shows which CLI command leads to the issue.
- The next call of `\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager::get` shows which dependency of this command leads to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late to the party, but I've managed to deal with this issue by running the following command.

```
php bin/magento setup:uninstall
```

This will remove any existing config files including `env.php` from the previous installation, properly uninstalling Magento and this will allow you to go through the installation process without issues.

I *assume* this error occurred, at least in my case, because Magento has been previously installed and configured in some way and your local configuration does not match the already existing one. It's basically looking for a shop that you are yet to create.

Hope this helps someone :)